# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

This is my code

```
public class Email {
    static Properties props;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String from = "some email";
        String to= "some other email";
        String host = "localhost";
        props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.host", host);
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
            message.setText("This is actual message");
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        }catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting following exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.cisco.ci.support.email.Email.main(Email.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:321)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 12 more
```

It seems that I do not have smtp server on my mac? any solutions?

Comment: Install SMTP on your Mac, or change your code to point to a real SMTP server (or a [fake](https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/) one).

Answer (score 2):

You either need to install a smtp Server on your mac, which is not that simple, or use an existing smtp server. Obviously you will need an account for that server, as there are not many smtp Servers without authentication in the wild.

E.g. Create a googlemail Account, then check: http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/ for example of how to use it!

Comment: You'll find other helpful information in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).